# Multiple git repositories with same base directory

Tags: git

I have two codebases, called `a` and `b`. Project `a` provides a common infrastructure that project `b` relies upon. However, all of the code for for project `b` is underneath the directory structure for project `a`. Here's an example:

```
a File0.cs
a Assets/Core/File1.cs
b Assets/Extension/File2.cs
```

So project`a` provides `File0.cs` and `File1.cs` and owns the `Assets` folder. Project `b` only provides `File2.cs`

Does git support this directory structure? If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: recommended reading: [Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does. It is called "submodule" in git jargon. You can get help on it with `git submodule --help`.

Though, it is not seen as very good style to depend on submodules, if possible, use various package/dependency managers like pip, gem, npm, bower etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you'er looking for is called a "Submodule":

[6.6 Git Tools - Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Basically you can tell git that a directory inside your repository is actually a *separate* repository, tracked elsewhere. This works at the directory level, not the file level.

From there, assigning individual files to a specific repository's directory is just a matter of creating symlinks.

```
myapp/
myapp/submodule/                    <-- submodule repository
myapp/submodule/foo.c               <-- shared file
myapp/foo.c -> submodule/foo.c      <-- shared file reference in parent dir
```

Windows support symlinks on NTFS, but it doesn't advertise the fact, making them slightly more difficult to deal with.

Comment: There are more problems with NTFS symlinks. Like you can only create one with `mklink` command if you are admin. :-/